# does std::set and std::queue change the address of their stored elements when adding or removing elements?

Tags: c++

I know that **vector** does dynamically change the address of stored elements when it is changed by some action like push or pop.

Is that true for the **set** and **queue**?

Comment: there is no `std::set::push` nor `std::set::pop`

Comment: much related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438086/iterator-invalidation-rules-for-c-containers

Comment: `std::queue` is not a container, it is a container adaptor. So the answer will depend on the type of the underlying container used by queue.

Comment: Click on the methods in the __Modifiers__ section here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set .  For example `std::set::insert` _"...No iterators or references are invalidated...."_  The so the same for `std::queue`.

Comment: Or, with `[std::set::erase]`: _"References and iterators to the erased elements are invalidated. Other references and iterators are not affected."_

Comment: Associative containers generally don't invalidate existing iterators to other elements. Queue, stack and priority queue are adaptors over existing containers so they don't really dictate how their operations will behave. vector will invalidate all iterators if reallocation happens, will invalidate all iterators past the element erased or inserted. You should consult the documentation for specifics.

Comment: Nice table of invalidation rules here - page down to [Iterator invalidation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container)

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number  thanks that is what I need

Comment: @DanielLangr  thanks that is what i need